# Fourier transform of even reflection

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

What is the Fourier transform of $f(-x)$? Can it be related to the Fourier transform of $f(x)$? Maybe, through odd/even properties?

Initially, I thought it is the same as the Fourier transform of $f(x)$. However, because of the scaling relation

$$\mathcal{F_{\omega}}f(-x) = \frac{1}{|-1|}\mathcal{F_{-\omega}}f(x)$$

Comment: What is $\int_{\infty}^{\infty}f(-t)e^{ist}dt$?

Comment: Just make $y := -x$ and see what you get in terms of $y$.

Comment: And what is the convolution of f with itself?

Comment: so Fourier(f(-x)) = -Fourier(f(x))

Comment: Ah, the scaling relation...

Comment: So, Fourier f(-x) is Fourier(f(x)) with a minus omega

Comment: Is it Correct now?

Comment: thanks!! Just edited the question. could you take a look?

Comment: You are using a table of Fourier transforms.  That does the trick, but provides no insight.

Comment: But is the answer correct? And I understand what is happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let:
$$\hat{f}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{itx}dx.$$
You want to evaluate:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(-x)e^{itx}dx $$
so you can make the change $u = -x$ so that:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(-x)e^{itx}dx = -\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}f(u)e^{-itu}du = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(u)e^{-itu}du$$
In other words, if $f(x) \to \hat{f}(t)$ then $f(-x) \to \hat{f}(-t)$.